# How to change function/argument name in all R files of a package

Tags: r, renaming

Lets say I have a package, which consists of 20 different R-files.

How can I change a function or argument name in all those 20 files, without opening all of them and search/replace the name individually for every file?

Or how can I find out all locations of that function/argument name?

Comment: Command line tools are pretty good at stuff like this. `sed` or `awk`, for example, depending on your platform. As for RStudio, I think you're looking at the "Whole word" button, not a "whole world" button. But there is a "Find in Files" option in the Edit menu that will let you search multiple files.

Comment: See also "Rename in Scope" in the Code menu. Not sure if it works project-wide or just in the current file, but it's pretty handy and a quick test would answer that question. [See quick demo in here](https://rviews.rstudio.com/2016/11/11/easy-tricks-you-mightve-missed/). (Edit: comments in that link indicate Rename in Scope was only for one file as-of a year ago, but go on to recommend Find in Files)

Comment: Oh yeah, I was always misreading it as whole world. I'll remove that from the question. :) Yeah sed/awk would be an option, but have a tricky syntax.

Comment: "Find in Files" is a nice tool! I didn't know that and it already solves the first part of my problem! Thanks!

Comment: Will this be a one time thing or need to do so regularly? If the latter, that is not an effective way of programming.

Comment: This would be a one time thing ;) Anyway, the "Find in Files" option in RStudio is already a great tool I wasnt aware of.